# Implement higher order functions and lambda

Tags: kotlin, lambda, higher-order-functions

i try to add to the higher order function an lambda expression. but my question is :
how can I implement the forEach function, which each element from the list with the passed
Function action calls?

```
import java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

    class LinkedList <T> {
        data class Node<T>(val data: T, var next: Node<T>?)

        private var first: Node<T>? = null


        fun addFirst(data: T) {
            val newNode = Node(data, first)
            first = newNode
        }

        fun isEmpty() = first == null

         fun clear(): Any {
           return LinkedList<T>().clear()
        }

        fun get(index: Int): Any {
            var position = 0
            var runPointer = first
            while (runPointer != null && position != index) {
                position += 1
                runPointer = runPointer.next
            }
            return runPointer?.data ?: throw IndexOutOfBoundsException()
        }

         
         
        fun forEach(action: (T) -> Unit) {  
            ...

        }
    }
```

Comment: Same way you implemented `get` but calling `action` on `runPointer.data`

Comment: I agree with @al3c, you just need to call action on each of the `runPointer.data` you encounter while you loop. Also, what is `clear()`'s contract here? It seems to be really really weird: it returns an empty list but doesn't do anything with `this` list.

Comment: can you show me an example with each of the functions, because it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using a `first: Node` you should do:

```
fun forEach(action: (T) -> Unit) {
    var p = first
    while (p != null) {
        action(p.data)
        p = p.next
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `forEach` is extension function  of Iterrable as in std lib

```
 fun <T> Iterable<T>.forEach(action: (T) -> Unit): Unit {
    for (element in this) action(element)
}
```

Source https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt

Comment: ok thanks but how can i do it without the iterable. How should i write it in here                          fun forEach(action: (T) -> Unit) {

Comment: Well you can use it with out Iterrable like `fun forEach..` but this is applicable  for only `LinkedList` type in other word the variable you call must be a child of the super class